# Expose a Kubernetes pod on a bare metal cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to expose a Kubernetes pod on a single node bare metal cluster without a domain. 
In my understanding I've the these options:

1. Expose using NodePort
2. Expose using an Ingress controller
3. Expose using ClusterIP and manually set an external IP

As I mentioned already, I only have a single node cluster. This means that the master is master and node at the same time directlly running on a fedora host system.

The simplest solution is to use a NodePort. But the limitation here is (if I'm right), that the service port will be automatically selected from a given port range.

The next better solution is to use an ingress controller. But for this I need a public domain which I haven't. So the ingress controller also doesn't fit to me.

What for other options do I have? I just want to expose my service directly on port 9090.

Comment: See `hostPort` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a custom port range for NodePort by adding this option to your [apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) settings (`/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`):

> --service-node-port-range portRange
>   Default: 30000-32767
>   A port range to reserve for services with NodePort visibility. Example:
>   '30000-32767'.
>   Inclusive at both ends of the range.

This is the part from Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) related to Services:

> If you want a specific port number, you can specify a value in the
>   `nodePort` field, and the system will allocate you that port or else the
>   API transaction will fail (i.e. you need to take care about possible
>   port collisions yourself). The value you specify must be in the
>   configured range for node ports.

Example for this answer was taken from the article [Hosting Your Own Kubernetes NodePort Load Balancer](http://blog.oestrich.org/2016/01/nodeport-kubernetes-load-balancer/):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    name: nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 80
      nodePort: 30080
      name: http
    - port: 443
      nodePort: 30443
      name: https
  selector:
    name: nginx
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not Option 3 ？ you can setup externalIPs to your node ip.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
...
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - your node ip
```

Also with NodePort, the service port can be specified.